# No response to google api call via javascript

Tags: javascript, google-api, google-authentication

I'am trying to get the emails of the gmails contact when a user is logged in order to make à field autocomplete with his list of frineds.

After reading a lot and trying a couple of sample code i juste can't get a response after :

```
var id_token = googleUser.getAuthResponse().id_token;
```

Here is the call for contact :

```
<div class="g-signin2" data-onsuccess="onSignIn"></div>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function onSignIn(googleUser) {
            var profile = googleUser.getBasicProfile();
            //alert('bingo');
            console.log('ID: ' + profile.getId()); // Do not send to your backend! Use an ID token instead.
            console.log('Name: ' + profile.getName());
            console.log('Image URL: ' + profile.getImageUrl());
            console.log('Email: ' + profile.getEmail());

            var id_token = googleUser.getAuthResponse().id_token;
            console.log("ID Token: " + id_token);
            var url = "https://www.google.com/m8/feeds/contacts/default/full?access_token=" + id_token + + "&alt=json";

            $.ajax({
                url: url,
                type: "GET",
                dataType: 'jsonp',
                cache: false,
                success: function (response) {
                    alert(response);
                },
                error: function (status) {
                    alert(status);
                }
            });

        };
</script>
```

I never get to see the alert(response) nor the alert(status)...

Thank you.

Comment: What's happening in the network tabs of browser debugging tools like Chrome Dev Tools?

Comment: Just a get with no respond...